# Detecting pinch/zoom in IE10 without preventing default behavior

Tags: javascript, touch, internet-explorer-10

In Javascript, I'm trying to detect when the user is pinching, **and at the same time allow them to do so.**

```
var elm = $("#wrapper")[0];
var myGesture = new MSGesture();
myGesture.target = elm;

elm.addEventListener("MSGestureChange", handleGesture);         
elm.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", function (e) {
    myGesture.addPointer(e.pointerId);
});
```

I'm getting the `MSPointerDown` event.

But as far as I can tell, I'm required to style the element in question (#wrapper) with `-ms-touch-action: none` (or pan-y pan-x) to be able to recieve the `MSGestureChange` event when pinching.

I don't want to prevent the default pinch behavior, so what are my options?

Is there a way around this, or am I stuck doing one or the other?

Comment: Do you have something like `return false;` in your function `handleGesture`? Normally the event should be bubbled...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect zoom changes by checking the ratios of a few window/document/screen variables - see http://jsbin.com/abuzaz/8

Detect zoom changes by registering events on the window `onscroll` and `onresize` events. If you are worried about a resize or scroll event getting "lost" (it can happen) then an ugly solution could be to also register a slow interval timer to double check.

You can detect the current pinch-zoom level by looking at the ratio of the `document.documentElement.offsetHeight` to the `window.innerHeight` - but this might be due to bugs/quirks (see below!).

You can detect the page zoom (ctrl-+) level by looking at changes to the `screen.deviceXDPI` in the onresize event.

For more fun, have a play with the green box on http://jsbin.com/otocer/12 - touch one finger then the other and you get a `MSPointerCancel` event when the second finger touches. But touch both at the same time and you get no event.

You often get a window scroll event when touch-zooming, but I am unsure you can depend 100% on it. It seems you get a window resize event at the end of touch-zooming (but maybe not always - see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/1065f624-32a8-4c80-8ced-998ba624763e)- try http://jsbin.com/otocer/17

Note that touch-zooming (not page zoom) has some **big** bugs:

- body scrollbars are totally wrong if body size changed after pinch-zoom - see http://jsbin.com/abuzaz/1 - or see http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/779009/ie10-pinch-zoom-doesnt-adjust-scrollable-area-size-after-body-size-is-changed
- `position:fixed` is wierd - see http://jsbin.com/iciqaf/1 (pink fixed position box can go off viewport if pinch-zoomed then scrolled).
- using CSS `html { -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y; }` disables pinch-to-zoom, but can make the page text unreadably small (depending on device, configuration, and page size), and I couldn't see that `-ms-viewport` would fix that.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the resize event is being fired in IE10 on pinch to zoom (in and out) which causes some issues with dynamically displayed, fixed positioned layers (as you said) that have dimensions set in percentages - ie. modal windows disappear on pinch to zoom. Your work above helped me solve that issue by adding a resize event listener and state tracking variable to basically redisplay the modal window on pinch to zoom.

Answer (score 0):

**note this comment is now obsolete with the final release of Windows 8**

In reading the doc applying the css style you've specified `-ms-touch-action:none` is what tells the browser that for that element, that the application should produce the javascript event that you want to catch.  So, effectively, I don't believe it's possible to have your cake and eat it too, either you get the JS event, or you get the built-in behavior ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/hh673557.aspx ).

Comment: You are wrong. The first link http://jsbin.com/abuzaz/8 shows detecting pinch-zoom and zoom (and it has *no* -ms-touch-action:none). The http://jsbin.com/otocer/12 link is to show the interaction between the -ms-touch-action:none and pinch-zoom (which you seem to agree there are problems with). Also what you said is a comment on my answer, not an answer in itself, oops. It took me significant time to write and validate my answer, and I appreciate it if you spend some time validating your concerns before posting.

Comment: Robcat -- I'm glad that they finally fixed this with the production release of Windows 8. At the time that the question was asked, and I answered it, IE 10 and windows 8 were not in the version that you're using...

Comment: Seems like this is still the case. The answer on https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/767646/ms-touch-action-does-not-allow-a-way-to-programmatically-prevent-default-touch-behavior says there is no programmatic way to prevent the default behavior in JS, only via touch-action.